# Axioms of an algebraic structures

Tags: group-theory

I have started going over the axioms of semi-group, monoid, group.

I was wondering, can we say that associativity is an axiom of the operation and not of the set? maybe I am wrong, but are there axioms that depends just on the operation or the set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. The Group axioms are properties of the composition operation, and not of the 'naked' set elements.

When we say '$\mathbb Z_2$ has an identity element' we really mean '$\mathbb Z_2$ has an identity element with respect to the standard + operation'. Of course that element is $0$. But we could use a different operation on the **set** $\mathbb Z_2 = \{0,1\}$ to make $1$ into the identity. Denote that operation by $++$. The new group structure is as follows.

$1$$++$$1=1$

$0$$++$$0=1$

$0$$++$$ 1=0$

$1$$++$$0=0$

We could go further again and put an operation $*$ on the **set** $\mathbb Z_2 = \{0,1\}$ to make it a monoid but not a group. That operation is just multiplication. The monoid operation is as follows.

$1*1=1$

$1*0=0$

$0*1=0$

$0*0=0$

In conclusion saying '$\mathbb Z_2$ is a group', '$\mathbb Z_2$ is a monoid' or 'This is the identity of $\mathbb Z_2$' are all dependent on what we use for the operation.

However in practice when we mention 'the group $\mathbb Z_2$' we mean the set $\{0,1\}$ taken with modular addition. Usually when we want to use a different operation we will specify. And when we want to talk about the bare set we will write $\{0,1\}$ instead of $\mathbb Z_2$.

Likewise for other familiar groups like $\mathbb Z_n , \mathbb R, \mathbb C, \mathbb R_{\ne 0}, \mathbb C _{\ne 0}$. However there is no obvious way to 'write out' the elements of the real line to make it clear we are not worried about addition.

In fact, given a group $(G,*)$ the only importance of the particular set $G$ is the cardinality. Given any other set $F$ with $|F|=|G|$, we can invent a group operation $\odot$ on $F$ such that the groups $(G,*)$ and $(F, \odot)$ are isomorphic.

Comment: All true. It should perhaps be spelled out explicitly that they are still axioms "of groups", and in different contexts it is common to say "the group" either about the set of elements or about that set _together with_ the operation, and this can make it sound like the axioms are about the set.